# easeljs rotation container get out of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, easeljs

I am new to EaselJS. I have a container that contains a shape and a text. I would like to rotate the container.
For some unknown reasons, `container.rotation = 270` took the container out of the screen. After investigating I think that the container size is really big (although the shape and the text are small) and therefore rotating it from (0,0) to 270 deg took the container out of the screen.
How can I set the container a height and width? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also sounds like although your contents are small, they are positioned far away from the Container's registration point. If you do this, and then rotate, the container is considered as large as the coordinates of the children (plus their dimensions).

It makes more sense to put your contents close to 0,0, and move the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setBounds(x,y,width,height) method to the Container() Class.

Full Documentation @ http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_setBounds

Comment: setBounds is handy if you have content that isn't accounted for already with `getBounds()`, such as Graphics. It probably makes more sense in that case to use the setBounds on the Shape itself, so that its transformation is accounted for separately.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are rotated around the registration point. So you need to set the registration point correctly.

See this sample. Here a rectangle is being rotated. But the same applies to container also. If you want to rotate around the center of the container then move the registration point to the center by setting them to width/2 and height/2.

```
container.regX=width/2
container.regY=height/2
container.rotation=30
```

After this you should move the registration point back to where it was (usually 0,0).

http://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_derossi/Rtx6K/1/